# -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass not working for Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The following script is being called from a batch file; everything works except for the 'Get-ChildItem'; which is the most important part. Not sure why I am able to create folder and files, but I can't loop through a directory. I have admin rights to the machine; I am using '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass' in the batch, and I also have full rights to the folders.

The line that is giving me trouble is: $files = Get-ChildItem $uploadFilePath after it errors out, it throws the rest of the script in error.

I am an amateur at PowerShell; and I managed to frankenstein this script together for multiple other examples; so please forgive me if you see anything that just looks out-right-wrong.

Would appreciate any advice!

Batch File:

```
set sninstancename=NAMEHERE
set snsuthorization=AUTHERE
set snstagingtable=TABLEHERE
set snrecordlimit=100

powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "_sn_upload_files.ps1" -sninstancename "%sninstancename%" -snsuthorization "%snsuthorization%" -snstagingtable "%snstagingtable%" -snrecordlimit "%snrecordlimit%"
```

PS Script:

```
<# Set global variables #>
    param (
        [string]$sninstancename,
        [string]$snsuthorization,
        [string]$snstagingtable,
        [string]$snrecordlimit
    );

    $bulkUploadCount = 0;
    $createBulkRecord = "true";
    $bulkRecordSysID = "";
    $bulkRecordNumber = "";
    $logFileFolderName = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd";
    $logFolderPath = "$($PSScriptRoot)\$($logFileFolderName)";
    $uploadFilePath = "";
    $sninstanceurl = "https://$($sninstancename).service-now.com/";
    $snstagingurlpostfix = "api/now/table/$($snstagingtable)";
    $snuploadapipostfix = "ecc_queue.do?JSONv2&sysparm_action=insert";

function makelog-folder () {
    $logFolderExists = Test-Path "$logFolderPath";

    if ($logFolderExists -eq $False) {
        New-item "$logFolderPath" -type directory | Out-Null
    }
}

function welcome-prompt () {
    Write-host "`n";
    Write-Host "ServiceNow - PowerShell Bulk Upload Utility. Version 1.0";
    Write-host "`n";
    Write-host "Please Enter the full file-path for the files you wish to upload.";
    Write-host "Target files should not be in the same directory as PowerShell Script";
    Write-host "`n";
    $filePath = Read-Host -Prompt "Path";
    $filePathExists = Test-Path "$filePath";

    if ($filePathExists -eq $True) {
        return $filePath
    } else {
        Write-host "The file-path: $($filePath) is invalid. ";
        Write-host "Push any key to exit.";
        $exit = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
        exit;
    }  

}

function Get-MimeType() { 
    param([parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)][ValidateNotNullorEmpty()][System.IO.FileInfo]$CheckFile) 
    begin { 
        Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Web"         
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$check_file = $CheckFile 
        [sting]$mime_type = $null 
    } 
    process { 
        if ($check_file.Exists) {  
            $mime_type = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($check_file.FullName)  
        } 
        else { 
            $mime_type = "false" 
        } 
    } 
    end { return $mime_type } 
}

function create-staging-table(){
    if ($sninstancename -And $snsuthorization -And $snstagingtable) {
        $uri = "$($sninstanceurl)$($snstagingurlpostfix)";
        $headers = @{"Authorization"=$snsuthorization};

        try {
            $answer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($uri)" -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Headers $headers;

            if ($answer.result.number) {
                $bulkRecordNumber = $answer.result.number;
                $answer.result | ConvertTo-Json -depth 999 -Compress | Out-file "$($logFolderPath)\$($bulkRecordNumber).txt" -Encoding ASCII;
                return $answer.result.sys_id;
            }
        } catch {
            <#
            $errorhandle = @{"Message"="Error";"StatusCode"=$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__;"Description"=$_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription;"File"=$fileName}
            $errorhandle | ConvertTo-Json -depth 999 -Compress | Out-file "$snlogfile" -Encoding ASCII -append
            #>
            Write-host "error";
            Write-host "Push any key to exit.";
            $exit = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
        }
    } else {
        Write-host "Missing parameters:";
        Write-host "Push any key to exit.";
        $exit = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
        exit;
    }
}

function upload-files(){
    if ($sninstancename -And $snsuthorization -And $snstagingtable -And $snrecordlimit) {

       Write-Output "Transfering Files, please Wait...";
       $files = Get-ChildItem $uploadFilePath; 

       for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
            $uri = "$($sninstanceurl)$($snuploadapipostfix)";
            $headers = @{"Authorization"=$snsuthorization};

            $fileContentEncoded = [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content "$($files[$i].FullName)" -encoding byte));
            $mimeType = $(Get-MimeType -CheckFile "$files[$i].FullName");
            $jsonbody = @{agent="AttachmentCreator";topic="AttachmentCreator";name="$($files[$i].BaseName)$($files[$i].Extension):$($mimeType)";source="$($snstagingtable):$($bulkRecordSysID)";payload=$fileContentEncoded} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

            Write-host "Uploading $($files[$i].FullName)";
            Write-host "Please wait ...";

            try {
                $answer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri" -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post  -Headers $headers -Body $jsonbody;

                if ($answer.records) {
                    $answer.result | ConvertTo-Json -depth 999 -Compress | Out-file "$($logFolderPath)\$($bulkRecordNumber).txt" -Encoding ASCII;
                    return $answer.result.sys_id;
                }
            } catch {
                #$errorhandle = @{"Message"="Error";"StatusCode"=$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__;"Description"=$_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription;"File"=$fileName}
                #$errorhandle | ConvertTo-Json -depth 999 -Compress | Out-file "$snlogfile" -Encoding ASCII -append
                Write-host "error";
                Write-host "Push any key to exit.";
                $exit = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-host "Missing parameters:";
        Write-host "Push any key to exit.";
        $exit = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
        exit;
    }
}

cls
$(makelog-folder);
$uploadFilePath = $(welcome-prompt);
$bulkRecordSysID = $(create-staging-table);
$(upload-files);
```

Error:

```
Path: C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Upload
get-content : Access to the path
'C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Upload\Files are Here' is denied.
At C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\PSPOCNEW\_sn_upload_files.ps1:107 char:62
+             $fileContentEncoded = [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content
"$($fil ...
+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\nick.g...\Files are
   Here:String) [Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsof
   t.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Exception calling "ToBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inArray"
At C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\PSPOCNEW\_sn_upload_files.ps1:107 char:77
+             $fileContentEncoded = [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content
"$($fil ...
+
~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Get-MimeType : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
'CheckFile'. Cannot convert value "Files are Here OLD File Upload  - Copy
(152).pdf File Upload  - Copy (153).pdf File Upload  - Copy (154).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (155).pdf File Upload  - Copy (156).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(157).pdf File Upload  - Copy (158).pdf File Upload  - Copy (159).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (160).pdf File Upload  - Copy (161).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(162).pdf File Upload  - Copy (163).pdf File Upload  - Copy (164).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (165).pdf File Upload  - Copy (166).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(167).pdf File Upload  - Copy (168).pdf File Upload  - Copy (169).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (170).pdf File Upload  - Copy (171).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(172).pdf File Upload  - Copy (173).pdf File Upload  - Copy (174).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (175).pdf File Upload  - Copy (176).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(177).pdf File Upload  - Copy (178).pdf File Upload  - Copy (179).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (180).pdf File Upload  - Copy (181).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(182).pdf File Upload  - Copy (183).pdf File Upload  - Copy (184).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (185).pdf File Upload  - Copy (186).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(187).pdf File Upload  - Copy (188).pdf File Upload  - Copy (189).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (190).pdf File Upload  - Copy (191).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(192).pdf File Upload  - Copy (193).pdf File Upload  - Copy (194).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (195).pdf File Upload  - Copy (196).pdf File Upload  - Copy
(197).pdf File Upload  - Copy (198).pdf File Upload  - Copy (199).pdf File
Upload  - Copy (200).pdf[0].FullName" to type "System.IO.FileInfo". Error:
"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file
name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
than 248 characters."
At C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\PSPOCNEW\_sn_upload_files.ps1:108 char:51
+             $mimeType = $(Get-MimeType -CheckFile "$files[$i].FullName");
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-MimeType], ParameterBindin
   gArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-MimeTyp
   e
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code there but from the errors this has nothing specifically to do with PowerShell.exe switches and more with improper variable expansion. There are potentially more issues here but I would start with this.

The issue you are having is you are not getting your properties to expand properly.

I see you making string that are *partially* expanding where they can like

> ```
> $mimeType = $(Get-MimeType -CheckFile "$files[$i].FullName");
> ```

Subexpressions `$()` are useful to wrap code inside strings to be sure that variables get expanded properly. In the case above they are not necessary.

```
$mimeType = Get-MimeType -CheckFile $files[$i].FullName
```

While in a string `"$files[$i].FullName"` is was impossible for PowerShell to know that you were pulling a property from one indexed element from `$files`. So what you would see is the entire `$files` rendered as a string hence the long message about exceeding string length.

You do this properly in other places though

> ```
> get-content "$($files[$i].FullName)"
> ```

The subexpression syntax is not required here though but shows how to proper expansion inside a sting.

You can read more about [this concept on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/).

Comment: Thank you! I made those changes as you suggested! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, well it's obvious my script has other issues; I did find out what was giving me the access denied error.  I added '-file' to my Get-ChildItems line. Looks like before it was pulling in directories and then trying to encode them.

So at least that part is fixed at least. :)